# Java Swing JMenuBar

Tags: java, swing, jmenubar

my JMenuBar is not showing AT ALL. This is just a barebones GUI. I have sat here for quite a while now, and I cannot see the problem, soo, as they say, four eyes are better than two.

Thanks.

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class MainGui{
    private DrawPanel drawPanel;
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JPanel drawPanel;
    private JMenuBar menuBar;
    private JMenu fileMenu, imgMenu, helpMenu;
    private JMenuItem fileNew, fileOpen, fileSave, fileExit;
    private JMenuItem imgBtn1;
    private JMenuItem hlpAbout;

    public MainGui(DrawPanel drawPanel){
    mainFrame = new JFrame("JDraw v1");
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    this.drawPanel = drawPanel;

    menuBar = new JMenuBar();
    fileMenu = new JMenu("File");
    imgMenu = new JMenu("Image");
    helpMenu = new JMenu("Help");

    fileNew = new JMenuItem("New File");
    fileOpen = new JMenuItem("Open File");
    fileSave = new JMenuItem("Save File");
    fileExit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    imgBtn1 = new JMenuItem("Useless Button");
    hlpAbout = new JMenuItem("About this program");

    mainFrame.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
    menuBar.add(fileMenu);
    menuBar.add(imgMenu);
    menuBar.add(hlpMenu);

    fileMenu.add(fileNew);
    fileMenu.add(fileOpen);
    fileMenu.add(fileSave);
    fileMenu.add(fileExit);
    imgMenu.add(imgBtn1);
    helpMenu.add(hlpAbout);

    mainFrame.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    mainFrame.pack();
    mainFrame.setSize(640,480);
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Works fine for me, once I fix the compilation errors of course.

Comment: Compilation errors; strange, I never got any. Of course I assume you removed the references to drawPanel?

Comment: Variable declared as 'helpMenu', referenced as 'hlpMenu'.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried to recompile after posting the last comment, and realised that in trying to fiddle with something I had made a typo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want to do:

```
mainFrame.setJMenuBar(menuBar);
```

not:

```
mainFrame.add(menuBar, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use:

```
mainFrame.setMenuBar(menuBar);
```